# Spring Integration - How To Throw error from service activator with TCP Adapters

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

I have a requirement where i am (my application) receiving commands (string values) in a Spring Integration channel through TCP connections. When I receive a command, the application sends it over to a router to route the request to different channels in order to activate services using service activators.

The router first validates the command. If the command is not valid the router should not allow further processing and a custom error message needs to be sent back to the sender (TCP Client). 
I want a solution where I can analyze my command before or during routing and send the error response without any further processing ?

Following are the configurations and code.

**Spring Integration Config**

```
    <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server"
    type="server"
    port="${port}"
    using-nio="true"
    serializer="stxEtxSerializer"
    deserializer="stxEtxSerializer" />

<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.server"
    channel="adiIncomingChannel"
    connection-factory="server" />

<channel id="adiIncomingChannel" datatype="java.lang.String" />

<channel id="toSA" datatype="java.lang.String" />
<service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                   ref="tcpMessageReceiver"
                   method="receiveTcpMessageBytes" />

<beans:bean id="tcpMessageReceiver"
      class="com.gcaa.adi.tcp.socket.TcpMessageReceiver" />

<channel id="toObAdapter" />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.server"
    channel="toObAdapter"
    connection-factory="server" />


<router input-channel="adiIncomingChannel" ref="cmdRouter"></router>    



<beans:bean id="cmdRouter" class="com.gcaa.adi.messaging.router.CommandRouter">
</beans:bean>
```

**Router Class**

```
public class CommandRouter{

public String contentRouter(byte[] cmdBytes){
    String channelName = null;
    String cmd = new String(cmdBytes);

    //Data Requests
    if(cmd.startsWith(AdiCommandType.DATA_REQUEST.getCode())){

        AdiCommandValidationModel validCmdModel = validateDataCommand(cmd);

        if(! validCmdModel.isValidCmd()){
            // TODO: Send the error to  requesting client. Error = "<ERROR::<DATA::REQUEST>::001>"
        }
        channelName = "toSA";


    } // Health Check Response
    else if(cmd.startsWith("<HEALTH::ACK>")){
        channelName = "toSA";
    }

    return channelName;
}

private AdiCommandValidationModel validateDataCommand(String cmd){
    AdiCommandValidationModel validModel = new AdiCommandValidationModel();
    validModel.setCmd(cmd);

    List<MatchedGroup> matchedCmdItems = GcaaUtil.matchByGroups("^<DATA::(\\d[1-31]-\\d[1-12]-20\\d\\d)::(\\d+)>", cmd);

    if(null != matchedCmdItems && matchedCmdItems.size() > 0){

        // 1. Check if request date is valid
        if(!GcaaUtil.isEmptyString(matchedCmdItems.get(0).getGroup())){
            boolean isValidCmd = GcaaUtil.isDateValid(matchedCmdItems.get(0).getGroup(), "DD-MM-YYYY");
            validModel.setValidCmd(isValidCmd);             
        }else{              
            validModel.setValidCmd(false);
        }

        // return if date is not valid
        if(! validModel.isValidCmd()){
            validModel.setErrorCode(AdiErrorCode.DATA_INVALID_DATE);
            return validModel;
        }

        // 2. Check that DI value is >=0. It should not be less than 0 or NULL
        if(!GcaaUtil.isEmptyString(matchedCmdItems.get(1).getGroup())){
            Integer di = null;
            try{
                di = Integer.parseInt(matchedCmdItems.get(1).getGroup());
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

            }
            if(di== null || di < 0){validModel.setErrorCode(AdiErrorCode.DATA_INVALID_DATE);
            return validModel;}
        }else{
            validModel.setErrorCode(AdiErrorCode.INVALID_COMMAND);
            return validModel;
        }
    }


    if(! validModel.isValidCmd()){
        validModel.setErrorCode(AdiErrorCode.INVALID_COMMAND);
        return validModel;
    }
    return validModel;
}
}
```

**Updated - Solution 2**

I have tried the solution referred by you in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284280/spring-integration-writing-to-a-error-queue-when-exception-happended-in-a-serv?rq=1) link but I am getting an error pasted below.

Updated Service Activator code is listed below. I have removed the validation from the Router class and moved it to ServiceActivator.

**Validation ServiceActivator**:

```
public void validate(Message<byte[]> msg){
    String channelName = null;
    String cmd = new String(msg.getPayload());

    AdiCommandValidationModel validCmdModel = validateDataCommand(cmd);

    if(! validCmdModel.isValidCmd()){
        // TODO: Send to error channel 
        String err = "<ERROR::"+validCmdModel.getCmd()+"::"+validCmdModel.getErrorCode().getCode()+">";
        Message<String> mb = MessageBuilder.createMessage(err, msg.getHeaders());
        throw new MessagingException(mb);
    }

    //Data Requests
    if(cmd.startsWith(AdiCommandType.DATA_REQUEST.getCode())){

        validCmdModel = validateDataCommand(cmd);

        if(! validCmdModel.isValidCmd()){
            // TODO: Send to error channel
            throw new MessagingException(new GenericMessage<String>(validCmdModel.getValdationMsg()));
        }
        channelName = "toSA";


    } // Health Check Response
    else if(cmd.startsWith("<HEALTH::ACK>")){
        channelName = "toSA";   
    }

}
```

**Modified Config for Validation ServiceActivator**

```
  <!-- Server side -->
    <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server"
        type="server"
        port="${port}"
        using-nio="true"
        serializer="stxEtxSerializer"
        deserializer="stxEtxSerializer" />

    <ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.server"
        channel="adiIncomingChannel"
        connection-factory="server" 
        error-channel="inputErrorChannel"/>


    <!-- <object-to-string-transformer input-channel="adiIncomingChannel" output-channel="adiIncomingChannelStr"/> -->

    <service-activator input-channel="adiIncomingChannel"
                       ref="adiInputValidator"
                       method="validate" />

    <channel id="adiIncomingChannel"/>
    <!-- <channel id="adiIncomingChannel" datatype="java.lang.String" /> -->
    <channel id="inputErrorChannel" />

    <channel id="toObAdapter" />

    <ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.server"
        channel="toObAdapter"
        connection-factory="server" />

    <transformer input-channel="inputErrorChannel"
    output-channel="toObAdapter"
    expression="payload.failedMessage.payload"/>

<!-- dataType attribute invokes the conversion service -->
    <channel id="toSA" datatype="java.lang.String" />

    <service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                       ref="tcpMessageReceiver"
                       method="receiveTcpMessageBytes" />

<!-- output-channel="toObAdapter" -->
    <beans:bean id="tcpMessageReceiver"
          class="com.gcaa.adi.tcp.socket.TcpMessageReceiver" />

    <beans:bean id="adiInputValidator"
          class="com.gcaa.adi.validation.AdiInputValidator" />
```

**Exception from solution 2**
    -*-*-***-*-*-*--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* IN

```
TcpConnectionFailedCorrelation -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-**-*
     Connection Correlation ID: null
     Connection Source: org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler#0
     Connection time: 1486465992372
     Cause = : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket
2017-02-07 15:13:13.183 ERROR 4444 --- [pool-2-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : Exception sending message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[10], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59521, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:59521:5677:9a7fd07e-716b-4d1c-8be6-c73223cea9db, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=ca87761a-4a39-5869-ad53-7e078cf40508, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1486465989192}]

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:123) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:176) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.onMessage(TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.java:88) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.sendToChannel(TcpNioConnection.java:371) [spring-integration-ip-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.run(TcpNioConnection.java:240) [spring-integration-ip-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to show the rest of your (upstream) configuration but, if the inbound request is via a gateway, you would typically throw an exception in the router and handle the error on the gateway's error-channel flow.

Comment: Thanks Garry. I have updated the question with config file and router class. I am thinking to work this around as follows. When a message is received first send it to a validator ServiceActivator. And if the input is not valid serviceactivator sends an error message to error channel. Otherwise if the input is valid the validator service activator will forward the received message to the other channels which lead to further processing. Kindly let me know if this is a good way to validate the received inputs in Spring-integration.

Comment: Yes, it's generally better to separate the validation from the routing.

Comment: Hi Gary can u see the last portion of my question where I have edited it with the exception which I am getting if I throw exception from service activator.

Comment: My best guess is you are not copying the `ip_connectionId` header to your outbound message. I need to see this ERROR log to confirm: `    logger.error("Unable to find outbound socket for " + message);`

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have updated the above question with my code which throws the messaging exception. I am copying the headers from the received message in to the newly created error message. Kindly see section "Updated - Solution 2", "Validation ServiceActivator:", "Modified Config for Validation ServiceActivator", "Exception from solution 2"

Comment: You are losing the headers here: `throw new MessagingException(new GenericMessage<String>(validCmdModel.getValdationMsg()));` Use a `MessageBuilder` and `.copyHeaders()` from `msg`.